# Assign Xml Values to dynamically created components

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, serialization, flex3

xml values are stored in 'arr' array collection. depending on the length of the array stored, the below described components are created and assign those values to relevant components dynamically.

For Example:

AdvanceSearch.mxml is one component, and another components as advanceSearchAtom.mxml. within 'advanceSearchAtom' has some sub components as textbox, combo box etc,. we can add many advanceSearchAtom.mxml inside 'AdvanceSearch.mxml'.

```
var container : AdvanceSearch;

var adv : advanceSearchAtom;

for(var i:int=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
  adv = new advanceSearchAtom();

  adv.field.text = arr[i].field; 
  adv.value.selectedIndex = arr[i].value;

  container.addChild(adv); 
}
```

Please let me know if anybody come across this type of problem. if any relevant link is appreciable. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention it, but I guess the problem is that you're getting null reference error (1009) on the following lines:

```
adv.field.text = arr[i].field; 
adv.value.selectedIndex = arr[i].value;
```

Am I right?

This is because `field` and `value` are not yet created. As per the default component instantiation, Flex creates the children only when it is required - i.e., when it is to be displayed.

You can either listen to the `creationComplete` event of the `AdvanceSearchAtom` component and update the values from there; or have `Binadble` public variables in the `AdvanceSearchAtom` class, bind them to `field.text` and `value.selectedIndex` and assign xml values to those variables in the loop.

Using creation complete:

```
public var container:AdvanceSearch;
public var searchItems:Array = [];
public var arr:Array;

//assuming that arr has been initialized with xml values.
var adv:AdvanceSearchAtom;
for(var i:int=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
  adv = new AdvanceSearchAtom();
  adv.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, onAtomCreated);
  container.addChild(adv); 
  searchItems.push(adv);
}

public function onAtomCreated(e:Event):void
{
   var adv:AdvanceSearchAtom = e.currentTarget as AdvanceSearchAtom;
   if(!adv)
      return;
   var index:Number = searchItems.indexOf(adv);
   adv.field.text = arr[index].field;
   adv.value.selectedIndex = arr[index].value;
}
```

Using data binding:

Inside AdvanceSearchAtom.mxml

```
<mx:TextInput id="field" text="{textValue}"/>
<mx:ComboBox id="value" selectedIndex="{comboIndex}"/>
```

In the script block of AdvanceSearchAtom.mxml

```
[Bindable]
public var textValue:String;

[Bindable]
public var comboIndex:Number;
var adv:AdvanceSearchAtom;
```

In the AdvanceSearch class:

```
for(var i:int=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
  adv = new AdvanceSearchAtom();
  container.addChild(adv); 
  adv.field.text = arr[i].field; 
  adv.value.selectedIndex = arr[i].value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to give this wonderful answer. Hope this helps mw to solve my problem. Thanks a lot.